# Can Someone help me to convert typescript code to React Code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dnd, react-data-grid

There is a package called react-data-grid. And there is an example [table](https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/canary/) on that particular package but the code is in TypeScript and also docs for this particular version are not there. I tried to convert the typescript to React. Everything was fine until I wanted to implement Drag and Drop. Some error is coming and I think that error is because I'm importing something in the wrong way. Can you tell me where I'm doing anything wrong?
Here is the [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-row-reorder-700-canary33-ed0mu?file=/src/RowRenderers.js).
The error in my local build is coming on RowRender.js in line number 44.
I also included the typescript file there.
You can also see the error if you just uncomment the line 72-74 of App.js component in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-row-reorder-700-canary33-ed0mu?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: can you share the error message? Thanks

Comment: the error is RowRenderer.js on line 44. And it says `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Rename .ts file to .tsx file. In another case TypeScript will not understand `<div>` `<Row>` and other react elements
- Update your imports regarding react-data-grid to: `import { Row, RowRendererProps } from "react-data-grid";`
- Update your import `import { useCombinedRefs } from  ...` to fetch hook from correct place.
- If you will  see error regarding default import for React - change `import React from 'react'` to `import * as React from "react";` or update `tsconfig` to support [synthetic imports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports)

`useCombinedRefs` - is internal function that is not exported, so you can't use it directly. Option #1 - write it yourself. Option #2 find the reason why you are trying to use internal function. Should be the better way.

```
function useCombinedRefs(...refs) {
  return useCallback(handle => {
    for (const ref of refs) {
      if (typeof ref === 'function') {
        ref(handle);
      } else if (ref !== null) {
        ref.current = handle;
      }
    }
  }, refs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the issue is still there. 
I only provided typescript file because I'm converting the code to React from it. It is not included in the code(i.e it is there only for reference). I'm not using RowRenderedProps anywhere in the react code. And I can't understand where they are exporting useCombinedRefs from. So I think I'm importing them worng. Can you please provide exact import statement for useCombinedRefs.

Comment: Where did you take `useCombinedRefs`  before?

Comment: I'm converting from a typescript file that uses same package. They used in there imports(`import { useCombinedRefs } from '../../../../src/hooks';`)(see rowRendere.tsx in sandbox). How do I import it. Vs code is not giving recommendation.

Comment: This should work `import { useCombinedRefs } from 'react-data-grid/lib/hooks';`

Comment: Already tried this. Compile Error - ` ./src/components/RowRenderers.js
peggy-v2    | Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-data-grid/lib/hooks' in '/app/src/components'`

Comment: Using like this `import { useCombinedRefs } from 'react-data-grid'` doesn't give compile error, but it is giving typeerror.

Comment: Sounds weird. Ofc. you can suppress TS error with `//@ts-ignore` but this is not the answer.

Comment: Sorry. This syntax is working `import  useCombinedRefs from 'react-data-grid'`, but still the error is thier.

Comment: Yes. This Error `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

Comment: The Same error is coming on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-row-reorder-700-canary33-ed0mu?file=/src/App.js:2578-2691) too. If you uncomment line 72-74. You can see the error.

Comment: I see. This is because we are trying to import from `.d.ts` files. This type of files doesn't contain a code - only declarations. Probably this is internal hook that should not be used outside of the lib?

Comment: So. Is there work around on it that you can suggest and get the code work?

Comment: Just checked the lib code - it's internal function in the bundle. It's not exported so you can't use it directly. However, if you are sure you need to use it - take it from the code (updated the post). But I am 99% sure this is the wrong way and issue is somewhere else.

Comment: I think the error is coming from there only. Because when we comment that line out, the code start working. I also tried to declaring ref but that also doesn't seem to working.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the help. Turns out when I'm using this internal function, the code is working.